# How much space required to merge two tables?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, windows-11, postgres-14

I have some large sets of tables that I partition by date.

Every day I run a query similar to this to merge the two tables

```
WITH moved_rows AS
(
  DELETE FROM tableA_20230531 RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO tableA_202305
SELECT * FROM moved_rows
```

The table called `tableA_20230531` contains all my data for 1 day - averages about 1Gbyte. The table
`tableA_202305` contains the data for the month so far, obviously this gets bigger as the month progresses.

Sometimes the query falls due to lack of space (**ERROR: 53100: could not extend file.... No space left on device** ).

I know how large the two tables are, and I know how much free space I have on the disk.

Is there any way of working out (before running) if I have enough space for the query to execute successfully?

Somedays it will happily work even if the available freespace is less than the size of the daily table.
Otherdays it will fail even with freespace more than twice the size of the daily table.

(no other users connected when this is running, whole database on same disk, one index, about 10% of the table size - an additional 100Mbyte per day.

Archiving, replication and checkpointing all left to original, as-installed default settings - that's my of saying I don't know!)

Comment: You have elided the file name from the message, which might carry useful information.

Comment: filename was "pg_tblspc/59625/PG_13_202007201/59627/635175.15"

Comment: When you mention the 1GB size of the table, are you including indexes?  Do the tables have the same indexes?

Comment: Is pg_wal on the same partition as the tablespace data is?  If so, that can make it hard to predict how much space you will need, and it would depend on things like your archiving, replication, and checkpointing configurations.